# Kaspersky blocks Google Chrome for no reason

Tags: google-chrome, browser, kaspersky

Actually, everything was ok. But today this program started to block Chrome and all other browsers.

The case is in parental control. I do know how it is called in English. A thing created to block some negative things from a child. Yes, browser is negative thing :)

But not at all. I do not want to block it. When I turn off Parental control chrome starts to work. When I turn on then Chrome is trying to close with a message from Kaspersky and when Chrome is closed and I try it this error occurs:

[image]

In English, it sounds like I have no access to this object.

But I did not block Chrome in Kaspersky (yesterday everything was ok)

[image]

Here all browsers are allowed.

[image]

And here, in program control, it is allowed!

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem. As it turned out, you only need to update the version of Google Chrome up to date and Kaspersky will stop blocking it.